# Fixing sources.list on arm archirecture

Tags: updates, software-sources, arm, do-release-upgrade

I have Linaro Ubuntu installed on ARM device (Zynq Mini-ITX development board).
Here is my

```
# lsb_release -a
```

output:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

I want to run do-release-upgrade but it says:

```
Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of
network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

W:Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty/Release Unable
to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
, W:Failed to fetch
http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty-security/Release Unable to find
expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file (Wrong
sources.list entry or malformed file)
, W:Failed to fetch
http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty-updates/Release Unable to find
expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release file (Wrong
sources.list entry or malformed file)
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or
old ones used instead.
```

And apt-get update doesn't work either:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main armel Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe armel Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-armel/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

I've tries Russian and US mirrors but there's no difference.
My network connection is o'k. I suppose I have to somehow repair my sources.list file. I've tried generating it at http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ but nothing worked. 
I read that I have to use main Ubuntu server for apt-get update but not its American mirror. Can anybody tell me how to do that?

What do I have to do?